# How to move incrementaly mongodb database to production?

Tags: mongodb, deployment

(Maybe I am missing the point here, but I was unable to find answer so far o.O)

I have online app that I develop locally on my PC with MongoDB (C#). I need to move database incremental changes to production *without* losing existing customer data in production database, and - preferably - with minimal (or even no) downtime...

How can I do that?

Or if my idea of nosql database is wrong; How should I solve experimental development of live database?

Comment: Same as with a production SQL database: very carefully! There's no single answer for this, it all depends on what change you're making.

Comment: @JohnnyHK There are tools for SQL databases like https://flywaydb.org/ I was wondering if the same apply to noSQL ones...